# Añadir query a la url en Angular 4

Tags: angular, sql

Llevo poco tiempo con el tema de Angular y me ha surgido una duda. ¿Hay alguna manera de añadir a la URL una query?

Por ejemplo tenemos la url:

```
www.miweb.com/libros
```

Y muestra un listado paginado con los libros. La paginación funciona correctamente pero la URL no cambia, entonces el usuario no podría compartir la URL para que cargue directamente la página deseada. Necesitaría que al cargar una página añadiera una query del estilo:

```
wwww.miweb.com/libros?page=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular está pensado para crear "single page applications" (Aplicaciones con una sola página), pero hace lo que quieres mediante un componente llamado `Router`. Las URL serían algo así como:

`www.miweb.com/` Carga la aplicación, llevándote a la pantalla inicial

`www.miweb.com/libros` Te lleva a la pantalla de los libros

`www.miweb.com/libros/24` Te lleva a la pantalla del detalle del libro con ID 24.
En los navegadores modernos se puede cambiar la URL sin que se recargue la página y Angular hace uso de esa habilidad.

Pero por temas de compatibilidad con navegadores antiguos se puede añadir una almohadilla (hash, #) para navegar sin que se recargue la página, teniendo URLs como `www.miweb.com/#/libros/24`, es cuestión de configuración.

Y, además, puedes añadir parámetros extras como si fueran una query para dar más información a la aplicación:
`www.miweb.com/#/libros/24?datoExtra=informacionExtra`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar *queryParams* en Angular de la siguiente forma:

- desde la plantilla:

`<a [routerLink]="['product-list']" [queryParams]="{ page: 99 }">Go to Page 99</a>`

- desde el controlador:

`this.router.navigate(['/product-list'], { queryParams: { page: pageNum } });`

Los *queryParam* son opcionales mientras que los parámetros de ruta son esenciales para determinar la ruta y, por lo tanto, obligatorios.

> The key difference between query parameters and route parameters is
>   that route parameters are essential to determining route, whereas
>   query parameters are optional.

Si necesitas más información: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html